# Class referencing Error - sometimes an issue

Tags: python

Okay so I did not know what to search for in order to answer this question.

In my code for some reason some of my classes can be referenced as per instructions by Python

```
class MyClass:
    """A simple example class"""
    i = 12345
    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'

x = MyClass()
```

In my code I have imported my custom python modules using

```
import [custom module]
from [custom module] import *
```

next I make a reference to the class

```
classRef = [classfunction]()
```

Below is my actual code, this module is called "main.py"

```
from Tkinter import *
import os, sys
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
from tkFileDialog import *
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
#custom python classes
import reader
import searchDog
from searchDog import *
from reader import *




class appGUI:
    def __init__(self,frame):
        #set windows size 600 by 300

        #frame = Tk()
        frame.geometry("600x300+30+30")
        self.openExcel = Button(frame, text = "Open Defect Excel", command = lambda: self.openExcelFile())
        self.openExcel.place(x=10,y=10,width=100,height=25)
        self.openDefectTextFile = Button(frame, text ="Open Text File", command = lambda: self.openDefectText())
        self.openDefectTextFile.place(x=10,y=40,width=100,height=25)
        self.startButton = Button(frame, text="Start",command = lambda: self.startLoadProcess())
        self.startButton.place(x=10,y=70,width=100,height=25)
    def openExcelFile(self):
        self.openTemp = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent = root, title = 'Select Defect Excel File')
    def openDefectText(self):
        self.openDefect = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent = root, title= 'Select Defect Text File')
    def start(self):
        self.startLoadProcess()


    def startLoadProcess(self):
        #text file where defect comments are stored
        filePath = self.openDefect

        #keyword condition to search for
        keyword = "18360" #probably will put this in a loop

        #create an instance of ReadFile from searchDog
        readInText = ReadFile()
        keywordSearch = searchFile()
        #----End searchDog Reference
        #create an instance of readExcel from ExcelFileHandle

        i = 2
        #searches for and writes the comments into a text file
        while self.readData(i, 2, self.openTemp) != None:
            keywordSearch.searchForKeywordText(self.readData(i,2,self.openTemp), filePath,i) #searchDog Function
            self.loadExcelFile.save(self.openTemp)
            i += 1

    def readData(self,inputRow,inputColumn,excelFilePath):

        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        self.loadExcelFile = load_workbook(filename = self.openTemp)
        self.excelWorksheet = self.loadExcelFile.get_sheet_by_name('Defects')
        self.rowInput = inputRow
        self.columnInput = inputColumn
        self.cellValue = self.excelWorksheet.cell(row=self.rowInput,column=self.columnInput).value
        return self.cellValue, inputRow


root = Tk()
app = appGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

the next module is called excelWiteIn.py

```
#built in modules from python
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

#my custom modules from the project
import searchDog
import main


class excelWriteInClass():

    '''
    writes data coming from searchDog into Defects page
    '''


    def writeToExcelFile(self,textLine,writeRow):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        self.searchDogRef = searchFile()
        self.appGuiRef = appGUI()

        self.excelDefectWorksheet = self.appGuiRef.loadExcelFile.get_sheet_by_name('Defects')
        self.excelDefectWorksheet.cell(row= writeRow, column = 11).value = textLine
```

the error I get is that the my reference is not defined specifically at this line:

```
        self.searchDogRef = searchFile()
        self.appGuiRef = appGUI()
```

I don't understand why sometimes referencing classes work and sometimes they do not.  Is this a PyDev glitch, is it an Eclipse glitch?

***Computer Information:

```
Eclipse V. Version: 3.6.2 Build id: M20110210-1200
Compiling under Python 2.7
   - installed modules --> openPyxl
using Latest PyDev plugin downloaded from Eclipse Market***
```

Comment: Think that this happens since you use 'from module import *' in one file and 'import module' in another file. Note that it is always better to use 'from module import <class>, <vars>' instead of '*' this would allow you to control your imports.

Comment: The reason you are getting the error is because you have not defined the `__init__` method in the class `excelWriteInClass`.

Answer (score 1):

If i correctly understood you then the problem is that you are using import/from .. import incorrectly. First of all there is no need to use both 'import module' and right after that call 'from module import ...'.

Modify main.py:

```
import os, sys

from tkFileDialog import <put here what you really need>
from Tkinter import <put here what you really need>

from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

#custom python classes
from searchDog import <put here what you really need>
from reader import <put here what you really need>
```

Modify excelWiteIn.py:

```
from main import appGUI
from searchDog import searchFile

#OR

self.searchDogRef = main.searchFile()# in case searchFile specified within main.py otherwise you need to specify proper path to module that contains it
self.appGuiRef = main.appGUI()# note that you have to add 'frame' here
```

EDITED - putting here you main.py with small fixes and questions/comments:

```
import os, sys # not used
from Tkinter import Tk, Button
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

#custom python classes
from searchDog import searchFile, ReadFile
from reader import <put here what you really need>

class appGUI(object):

    def __init__(self, frame):
        #set windows size 600 by 300 

        #frame = Tk()
        frame.geometry("600x300+30+30")
        self.openExcel = Button(frame, text = "Open Defect Excel", command = lambda: self.openExcelFile())
        self.openExcel.place(x=10, y=10, width=100, height=25)
        self.openDefectTextFile = Button(frame, text ="Open Text File", command = lambda: self.openDefectText())
        self.openDefectTextFile.place(x=10, y=40, width=100, height=25)
        self.startButton = Button(frame, text="Start",command = lambda: self.startLoadProcess())
        self.startButton.place(x=10, y=70, width=100, height=25)

    def openExcelFile(self):
        # root? it not specified here
        self.openTemp = askopenfilename(parent=root, title='Select Defect Excel File') 

    def openDefectText(self):
        # root? it not specified here
        self.openDefect = askopenfilename(parent=root, title='Select Defect Text File') 

    def start(self):
        self.startLoadProcess()

    def startLoadProcess(self):
        #text file where defect comments are stored
        filePath = self.openDefect

        #keyword condition to search for
        keyword = "18360" #probably will put this in a loop

        #create an instance of ReadFile from searchDog
        readInText = ReadFile()
        keywordSearch = searchFile()
        #----End searchDog Reference
        #create an instance of readExcel from ExcelFileHandle

        i = 2
        #searches for and writes the comments into a text file
        while self.readData(i, 2, self.openTemp):
            keywordSearch.searchForKeywordText(self.readData(i, 2, self.openTemp), filePath, i) #searchDog Function
            self.loadExcelFile.save(self.openTemp)
            i += 1

    # excelFilePath not used at all
    def readData(self, inputRow, inputColumn, excelFilePath):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        # not sure that this is a good idea to load workbook each time
        self.loadExcelFile = load_workbook(filename = self.openTemp) 
        self.excelWorksheet = self.loadExcelFile.get_sheet_by_name('Defects')
        self.rowInput = inputRow
        self.columnInput = inputColumn
        self.cellValue = self.excelWorksheet.cell(row=self.rowInput, column=self.columnInput).value
        return self.cellValue, inputRow


root = Tk()
app = appGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Okay, I made the changes to the two files but I am still having the same issue and now references that once worked are saying they no longer exist specifically in: 'code'readInText = ReadFile() and     keywordSearch = searchFile()'code'.  I think I may re-code my code because create different classes to create individual modules seems to be more of a pain in the neck than a helper.  In any case it should not randomly stop working like it is now.   @Artsiom Rudzenka

Comment: sorry forgot to mention you @Artsiom Rudzenka and clean up my previous comment  `readInText = ReadFile() and keywordSearch = searchFile()`

Comment: This simply means that you have to add references to these into your main.py. I could not say you where they are since i have not all your sources - probably you have to use something like 'from searchDog import searchFile' but you have to go through your modules and find real destination for this classes

Comment: Edited my sample try to take a look into it and do let me know whether it help or not